# "Flatten" cells and show value if it exists

Tags: excel, excel-formula, openoffice-calc

I am in search of a formula that can show a content of a cell(if it has one)in a specific range. Here is an image of what am trying to do:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want for output if there is more than one entry in a column

Comment: Would a Power Query solution be acceptable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will there always only be one value in that column? There is a CONCATENATE function that will just join everything together, so if everything else is blank it will give what you want... or a much simpler &

`=CONCATENATE(E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9)`

or

`=E3&E4&E5&E6&E7&E8&E9`

Or, if you have access to [`CONCAT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) you could use:

```
=CONCAT(E2:E9)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(E2:E9,MATCH("zzz",E2:E9))
```

[image]

This assumes that the content in that specific range is text and not a number (e.g. "11a" and not 11). An alternative formula that can handle either case is the following (thanks to @JvdV):

```
 =LOOKUP(2,1/(E2:E9>0),E2:E9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could use, in `E12`, copied across :

```
=LOOKUP("zzz",E2:E10)
```

[image]